# How to manipulate string properly in C

Tags: c, string, loops

I'm still new in C. I'm doing an enviroment variable task and I'm having a problem in processing my string. I would like to pass a variable that represent the environment variable, and replace a value that has ${...} with environment value if that string are same as the enviroment key. Here are the codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void replace_env(char *string, char *env)
{
    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int val_length;
    int location2[100];
    char *tmp3[BUFSIZ];
    char env_key[BUFSIZ];
    char env_val[BUFSIZ];
    char env_var[sizeof(env)][BUFSIZ];
    char user_input[BUFSIZ];
    char final_string[BUFSIZ];
    char tmp_key[100][BUFSIZ];

    tmp3[x]=env;
    strncpy(env_var[x],tmp3[x],sizeof(tmp3));

    for(x=0;env_var[y][x] != '=';x++)    //this is to get the environment key
    {
            env_key[x] = env_var[y][x];
    }
    x++;
    for(j=0;env_var[y][j] != '\0';j++)    //this is to get the environment value
    {
            env_val[j]=env_var[y][x];
            x++;
    }
    val_length = strlen(env_val);
    j=0;
    y=0;
    strncpy(user_input,string,sizeof(user_input));

    for(x = 0;user_input[x] !='\0';x++)
    {
     if (user_input[x] =='$')
      {
        x++;
        if(user_input[x] == '{')
         {
           x++;
           y=0;
           while(user_input[x]!='}')
           {
             tmp_key[i][y] = user_input[x];
             x++;
             y++;
           }
          i++;
          }
       }
    }
    tmp_key[i][y]='\0';
    i=0;
    for(x = 0;user_input[x] !='\0';x++)    //I think my problem is starting from here.
    {
     if (user_input[x] !='$')
      {
       final_string[j]=user_input[x];
       j++;
      }
      else
          {
           x++;
           if((user_input[x]== '{')&&(strncmp(tmp_key[i],env_key,sizeof(tmp_key))==0))
           {
            while(user_input[x]!='}')
            {
             x++;
            }
            strcat(final_string,env_val);
            j=j+val_length;
           }
           else    
              {
                final_string[j]=user_input[x];
                j++;
              }
         }
    }
    printf("output result = %s \n",final_string);
}

int main() {
    char s[100];
    sprintf(s, "jack${ABC}zack${DEF}");
    replace_env(s, "ABC=/home/fikrie/Documents");
    replace_env(s, "DEF=/tmp");
    if (strcmp(s, "jack/home/fikrie/Documentszack/tmp")==0) {
            printf("pass\n");
    } else {
            printf("fail\n");
    }
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------\n");

return 0;
}
```

To make it more clearer, here are the result:

```
env_var = ABC=/home/fikrie/Documents 
env_key = ABC 
env_val = /home/fikrie/Documents 
input = jack${ABC}zack${DEF} 
after strcat result is = jack/home/fikrie/Documents 
j value is 26 
after strcat result is = jack/home/fikrie/Documentszack/home/fikrie/Documents 
j value is 52 
output result = jack/home/fikrie/Documentszack/home/fikrie/Documents 
env_var = DEF=/tmp 
env_key = DEF 
env_val = /tmp 
input = jack${ABC}zack${DEF} 
output result = jack{ABC}zack{DEF}ocumentszack/home/fikrie/Documents 
fail
--------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, ABC are sent into the replace_env function. And it does replace the ${ABC} properly, followed with a string zack.Then the problem occures where ${DEF} are replaced with ABC key and not maintained as ${DEF}

When the DEF are sent during the second call of replace_env function, things got more wierd. Both ABC and DEF are not recognized. Even worse, the character at the back are still there.

My expectation is:

```
For the first call of replace_env:
jack/home/Fikrie/Documentszack${DEF}

For the second call of replace_env:
jack/home/Fikrie/Documentszacl/tmp

after the strcmp passed, the final_string will be cleared again.
```

All help are really appreciated. I dont expect an answer. I prefer a knowledge or guidance rather than just solving it blankly. Just need a clear explanation on my fault because I have been editing this code for almost a month and everything looks so blurry now. I know there are ways to solve it using memory functions, allocation etc. But this task is about string manipulation. I am running this on Ubuntu OS. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: A note about `strncpy`: it does not guarantee terminating `'\0'` at the end of target string. It's not really a proper string function, but misleadingly named special purpose memory copy function. Use `strncat` or `snprintf` instead, if you want a *string* result.

Comment: @hyde: If I'm not mistaken, strncat will copy the string into destination without replacing the older string right? Thanks for suggesting snprintf. I will consider to use it more after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you didn't ask for this, but consider this. Learning the C string functions is worth your time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sub(char *s, char *env, char *value) {
        char buf[BUFSIZ], *src = s, *dst = buf;
        int n = strlen(env);
        while(*src) {
                if(strncmp(src, env, n) == 0) {
                        dst += strlen(strcpy(dst, value));
                        src += strlen(env);
                } else {
                        *dst++ = *src++;
                }
        }
        *dst = 0;
        strcpy(s, buf);
}

void replace_env(char *s, char *env) {
        char copy[BUFSIZ], tmp[BUFSIZ];
        strcpy(copy, env);
        char *eq = strchr(copy, '=');
        if(eq == 0) {
                printf("No '=' found in '%s'\n", env);
                return;
        }
        *eq = 0;
        sprintf(tmp, "${%s}", copy);
        sub(s, tmp, eq+1);
}

int main() {
    char s[100];
    sprintf(s, "jack${ABC}zack${DEF}");
    replace_env(s, "ABC=/home/fikrie/Documents");
    replace_env(s, "DEF=/tmp");
    if (strcmp(s, "jack/home/fikrie/Documentszack/tmp")==0) {
            printf("pass\n");
    } else {
            printf("fail\n");
    }
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does solve my problem. But learning a code and writing a code is totally 2 different thing. I am still uncapable of utilizing the string manipulation. It's not that I don't like to use your code. I just dont feel the satisfaction of solving my problem. Nevertheless, I still appreciate your code. I will use it as a great guidance.

Comment: With all due respect, your code was overly complex for the problem is was trying to solve. You had a 87 line function with a half dozen char buffers, two of them two dimensional. Functions should be short, concise and do one simple thing. No would be able to look at your function and figure out what it does without a long long study.  Sometimes it's better to just start over when you find yourself deep in hole as you did. Divide the problem up into short functions, write them one at a time and test them as you go. Perhaps a good next step would be to study the code I gave you, then put it

Comment: aside and try rewrite it yourself. If you get stuck, go back to my code and figure out what it does line by line. You can't learn code in a vacuum, everyone learns code by trying and looking at example code. Always to try simplify, simplify, simplify. Good luck.

Comment: Yes. I totally agree with you. It is too long for a simple task. And it was not worth using a lot of memory for this. I realize what I wrote was processing a string manually which is to search character by character. Your code help me realize that there was an automatic way to do it. Thank you for your advice. I will start all over again and hope this time it will get more clearer.